# Problems importing jsPDF module into javascript

Tags: javascript, npm

I seem to be having trouble figuring this problem out. I have been trying to make a program to download a pdf from a webpage using the jsPDF npm module.

I have downloaded it and tried to import it in two different ways:

1. Importing through the node.js require statement

`const pdf = require("jsPDF");`

I have tried to run it with the web server and find that the require statement is not supported. So I turned to browserify to compile in to a bundle.js and get a large error that says:

> SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
> at DestroyableTransform.end [as _flush]
> at DestroyableTransform.prefinish
> at DestroyableTransform.emit
> at prefinish
> at finishMaybe
> at endWritable
> at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end
> at DestroyableTransform.onend
> at Object.onceWrapper
> at DestroyableTransform.emit

That are all pointing to different files within the browserify package.

2. Importing through the default javascript import statement

`import {jsPDF} from "jsPDF";`

and get an error saying

> Failed to resolve module specifier "jspdf". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I am running the server with the Live Server vscode plugin and I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

From their github page

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
```

Not

```
import {jsPDF} from "jsPDF";
```

Comment: When I enter it that way it does not make a difference in the error that I get